# C++ Access violation reading location in single link list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am using c++ to implement a single link list of integers. My program simply asks the user to fill the list with 5 integers, the program should then delete any even integer and print the list after deletion.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class IntSLLNode
{
public:
    IntSLLNode()     { next = 0; }
    IntSLLNode(int i, IntSLLNode *ptr = 0)
    {
        info = i;
        next = ptr;
    }
    int info;
    IntSLLNode *next;
};
class IntSLList
{
public:
    IntSLList() {head = tail =0; }
    void AddToTail(int);
    void DeleteNode(int);
    void DisplayList();
    void deleteEven();
    IntSLLNode * getHead()
    {
        return head;
    }
private:
    IntSLLNode *head, *tail;
};
void IntSLList::AddToTail(int el)
{
    if (tail != 0) // if list not empty;
    {   tail->next = new IntSLLNode(el);
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    else
        head = tail = new IntSLLNode(el);
}

void IntSLList::deleteEven()
{
IntSLLNode *current;
current=head;
int  num;
while (current!=0)
{
    num=current->info;
    current=current->next;
    if(num%2==0)
    {
        DeleteNode(num);
    }
}
}
void IntSLList::DeleteNode(int el)
{
    if(head !=0)
        if(head==tail && el==head->info)
        {
            delete head;
            head=tail=0;
        }
        else if(el==head->info)
        {
            IntSLLNode *tmp=head;
            head=head->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            IntSLLNode *pred, *tmp;
            for(pred=head, tmp=head->next;
                tmp!=0 && !(tmp->info==el);
                pred=pred->next, tmp=tmp->next);
            if(tmp!=0)
            {
                pred->next=tmp->next;
                if(tmp==tail)
                    tail=pred;
                delete tmp;
            }
        }
}

void IntSLList::DisplayList()
{
    IntSLLNode *current;
    current=head;
    if(current==0)
        cout<<"Empty List!";
    while (current!=0)
    {
        cout<<current->info<<" ";
        current=current->next;
    }
}
```

I got Unhandled exception at 0x002c1744 in ex4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefeee in statment int num=current->info; Can anyone suggest how to solve this?

Comment: Perhaps your code would like to be properly formatted?

Comment: Look at that error as a not-so-subtle hint that the address held in the pointer `current`  being dereferenced is bogus. Now walk backward in your code and see if you can see how it could be so. Consider what your `DeleteNode` function does, and what it could possibly mean to the *caller* of that function, in this case `deleteEven()`. What do you think `current` is pointing to when `DeleteNode()` returns and you're back in `deleteEven()` ?

Comment: Where is `num=current->info` line?

Comment: 0xfeeefeee means you are accessing a pointer that you freed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations

Comment: seems unnecessary to look up the int again when you delete, why not just pass the pointer to DeleteNode?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this, but I think the problem is laid here:

```
void IntSLList::deleteEven()
{
    IntSLLNode *current;
    current=head;
    while (current!=0)
    {
        if(current->info%2==0)
            DeleteNode(current->info);
        current=current->next; // this line
    }
}
```

I think there is a relation between deleted node which is preformed in the `if` statement and your next line. If you delete that specific pointer which points to an element in `DeleteNode()` then your `current` which it might be deleted till now will be pointing to a wrong address.

**EDIT**

```
void IntSLList::deleteEven()
{
    IntSLLNode *current;
    current=head;
    while (current!=0)
    {
        if(current->info%2==0)
        {
            int ind = current->info;

            current=current->next;
            DeleteNode(ind);
        }
        else
        {
          current=current->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot MahanGM :) I placed current=current->next; before the deletion and it works perfectly. I updated my code.

Comment: @user1477701 if that is all you did and it "works perfectly" consider it yet-more undefined behavior. Moving that line means you're now deleting the node *after* the one you wanted to delete, and you're *still* dereferencing an invalid node pointer on the next go around, only now *before* rather than after DeleteNode. This answer is correct, but your solution certainly is *not* if implemented as you described.

Comment: @user1477701 WhozCraig is telling the right thing. You have to set your current node based on that `if` statement and yet I'm not sure again because your code has a bad implementation. Check my edit.